# How to take multiple data types in single line on java?

Tags: java

I am new at coding and now I am learning Java. I tryed to write something like calculator. I wrote it with switch case but then I realized I must take all inputs in single line. For example in this code I took 3 inputs but in 3 different lines. But I must take 2 input and 1 char in single line. First first number second char and then third number. Can you help me ?

```
 Public static void main(String[] args) {
    int opr1,opr2,answer;
    char opr;
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    opr1=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter operation for");
    opr=sc.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter second number");
    opr2=sc.nextInt();

    switch (opr){
        case '+':
            answer=opr1+opr2;
            System.out.println("The answer is: " +answer);
        break;
        case '-':
            answer=opr1-opr2;
            System.out.println("The answer is: " +answer);
        break;
        case '*':
            answer=opr1*opr2;
            System.out.println("The answer is: " +answer);
        break;
        case '/':
            if(opr2>0) {
                answer = opr1 / opr2;
                System.out.println("The answer is: " + answer);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You can't divide to zero");
            }
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown command");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have to take it in a single line?

Comment: Because no one would use calculator like this. The goal is not a calculator, the goal is to learn how to make it. As I mentioned I am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way

```
System.out.print("Enter a number then operator then another number : ");
String input = scanner.nextLine();    // get the entire line after the prompt 
String[] sum = input.split(" ");
```

Here `numbers` and `operator` separated by `"space"`. Now, you can call them by `sum array`.

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(sum[0]);
String operator = sum[1];   //They are already string value
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sum[2]);
```

Then, you can do as you did than.

Comment: Thank you, but when I am typing char in the case it wants string type. That is way I can't write chars to it. Because my operation is string.

Comment: But it didn't work. when I am trying to control it it gives error. Another problem is mentioned  top of this your answer.                                                                                         Enter a number then operator then another number : 1+2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1+2"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
 at Scratch.main(scratch.java:8)

Comment: @RashadAliyev You have to separate them by `**space**` I said in my answer. I think you didn't read correctly. When you are inputting `1+2` You can't directly separate them. You have to try this way `1 + 2` Now, it will work. You were having error cause, `1+2` isn't `int` `+` is `char` or `string` type data. So, I wrote `input.split(" ")`. Here it is separating by `space`. I hope you understand what I am trying to say

Comment: Sorry, You are right. I tried it now it is working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter number, operation and number. For example: 2+2");
    String value = scanner.next();

    Character operation = null;
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        Character c = value.charAt(i);
        // If operation is null, the digits belongs to the first number.
        if (operation == null && Character.isDigit(c)) {
            a.append(c);
        }
        // If operation is not null, the digits belongs to the second number.
        else if (operation != null && Character.isDigit(c)) {
            b.append(c);
        }
        // It's not a digit, therefore it's the operation itself.
        else {
            operation = c;
        }
    }

    Integer aNumber = Integer.valueOf(a.toString());
    Integer bNumber = Integer.valueOf(b.toString());

    // Switch goes here...
}
```

Note: didn't validate input here.